# ICC color profile only loads after switching graphics mode?

Tags: drivers, graphics, color-management, icc

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell XPS15 laptop. I've loaded an .icm profile, but it only works 50% percent of the time...

I've also noticed now that switching it within the color manager does not seem to be working. (It did before) However, when plugging in an external display, the color profile is loaded. I can also get it to load myself by switching from the Nvidia to the Intel GPU with the prime indicator.

Obviously, I'd like my color profile to load 100% of the time when logging into my laptop. How is this achieved?

---

What I've done so far:

- Installed nvidia drivers, xsettings and prime-indicator
- Applied an .icm profile through the built in color manager
- Aquired an external monitor and plugged it in/out every day
- Noticed my color profile wasn't loading
- Added the .icm file to ~/.color/icc, ~/.local/share/color/icc and ~/.local/share/icc
- Downloaded software to try to apply the profile (Argyll CMS)

But still, I can only get the profile to load when switching to the Intel GPU. (And even that doesn't work 100% of the time...)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone using bumblebee and intel-virtual-output where the HDMI port is wired to the Nvidia chip, DisplayCal and Color can only set the color profile for internal screen only.

With xcalib, you can specify the display to apply the color profile to. In the default settings, :8 is the virtual display that the Nvidia runs on:

```
xcalib -d :8.0 path_to_profile.icc
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated to kernel 4.7; fixed the issue.

Comment: It would be nice if you describe in greater detail how to upgrade your kernel to 4.7 so that your answer becomes more helpful.

Comment: Well, this question was not about kernel upgrading. In case somebody doesn't know how to upgrade their kernel, they can find an answer on this very website.